# performSegueWithIdentifier doesn't work - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to use performSegueWithIdentifier when user taps in a row of a table view. How ever, it doesn't work and i have the next error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not perform segue with identifier 'categoriesS'. A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.'
```

I googled the error, but i don't find anything. I've already create the push segues in the storyboard and set them the identifiers that I use in my code.
This is my code(PD: Im using this tableview, as a side bar menu):

```
import Foundation

class menuVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    var opciones = [String]()
    var segues = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTable.delegate = self

        opciones = ["Categories","My Coins","Get Coins","Share","LogOff","Exit"]
        segues = ["categoriesS","myCoinsS","getCoinsS"]
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(opciones[indexPath.row])

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segues[indexPath.row], sender: self)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = opciones[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }   
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you may be using a custom class for your segue but that custom class isn't implemented correctly

Comment: Thanks that was my error, I was using a custom segue class. I got confused because as i said im using this for a sidebar menu, and the sidebar menu use a costum class of segue. I change it to the normal class, and works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have given a wrong segue as console clearly stated that. You are looking for '`categoriesS`' which is in '`segue`' array, but you are passing from '`opciones`' array. Look closely.

**Edit** 
I saw your edit, looks like u have populate your table using different array, but u have used other array in didselectrow.please check it

Comment: I corrected that, and edited my post. Still having the same error.